# What is the best/easiest way to redefine a built-in angular service?

Tags: angularjs, cors

In our app, we are making cross domain requests, and so we have to use CORS. Since IE does this in a non-standard way, we created our own service (which has a dependency on `$http` for non-IE requests) that would handle all this for us. This all works fine within this app. However we have some non-app specific library code that needs to make requests. So, if these services in our library code simply use `$http`, the requests would not work in the app that needs to do CORS. However, we don't want these services injecting our CORS service, because that would break requests in apps that aren't doing cross-domain requests.

With all that being said, my end goal is to have the library code inject and use `$http` for all necessary requests. Then, in the specific apps, it could define how `$http` works. I initially thought I could just redefine the provider for `$http`. Something like this:

```
angular.module("myCorsApp").provider("$http", function() {
    return {
        $get: function(CORShttpService) {
            return CORShttpService;
        }
    }
});
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Circular dependency: CORShttpService <- $http <- $compile
```

I'm not sure I understand where the circular dependency is coming from. Does `$compile` have a dependency on the providers or something?

My real question is if I'm even going about this the right way. If there wasn't the circular dependency, I would think this would accomplish exactly what I want. Is there some workaround I can do to make this work? Is there a better/more correct way of doing this?

If it helps at all, the `CORShttpService` has the following dependencies: $q, $rootScope, $http, $timeout. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around a bunch in the Angular docs, I decided that the best approach here was to "decorate" the `$http` service. This done with the [decorator function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide#decorator) of the `$provide` service. So, I ended up with something like this:

```
angular.module("myCorsApp").config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator("$http", ["$delegate", "$q", "$rootScope", "$timeout", function($http, $q, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        return function(requestConfig) {
            //CORS logic using $http (basically what was the CORShttpService)
        }
    }]);
});
```